# Win10's File Explorer no longer shows 16x16 thumbnails

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, thumbnails

(Actually, I found out in Directory Opus, which I use as File Explorer replacement, but FE behaves the same way.)

Larger thumbs show correctly, like in Tiles View, or Medium/Large Icons view. So it doesn't seem to have to do with the option to view thumbnails in FE's settings, nor in Performance settings: both settings are correct.
Leo of Directory Opus assumes the Registry may be messed up, which sounds plausible. But I have no idea what to look for (and not only because of the cryptic key names).

What I tried so far:

- use CCleaner to find Registry issues and fix them
- cleared the thumbnail cache

No avail. Any tips?

Comment: Hard to know if the registry has been modified.  Try the following:  Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.  dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup  dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth  SFC /SCANNOW   Allow to complete, restart and test.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, John. Comments don't allow formatting text, but I assume we're talking about two dism commands, and an sfc, right?

Comment: Yes try the 2 DISM commands and SFC

Comment: @John That doesn't seem to solve it. Thanks for your tip anyway.

Comment: You need to do a Windows 10 Repair Install. I will add a complete answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

One reasonably certain way to repair this issue is a Windows 10 Repair Install.

Go to the Media Creation Link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

> Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run.
>
> If the Repair will not run as per above, use the Download button to
> create a USB Windows Installation key, then run Setup on the USB Key.

This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.

**First:**

Start with the option to Keep Everything.

If this does not work as expected,

**Second:**

You can also Keep Data, or Keep Nothing. Keep Nothing is very close to a clean install.

Comment: Sure, repair install can fix anything, but is it really absolutely necessary?

Comment: Since the repair steps prior to doing a Repair did not work, then a Repair is the next step. In most cases, the first method (Keep Everything) works and is very simple and easy to do.

Comment: But this takes a long time and should only be the last resort, even so, it might be better to run system restore first...

Comment: You can try a system restore, but the restore point needs to be there. Repair is download time (about an hour) and install time (about an hour).

Comment: So fast? Why on my computer with HDD it takes hours to complete?

Comment: With a HDD it may take two hours to install.  I have done these before (numerous times). Even with a HDD (I have a Laptop with one), repairs still get done in reasonable time. You can always just leave it and let the error stay.

Comment: I'm with Xeнεi Ξэnвϵς on this: a repair install seems like huge overkill. And if that doesn't work either? Buy a new PC, I suppose?  /s

Comment: On a decent computer, a Repair Install is several steps and watching paint dry for a couple of hours. Not really much overkill to that. I have done a Repair Install at a conference on the move.